# ¿Como ignorar errores de sintaxis conservando el autocompletado en netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, sintaxis

Primero que todo seré mas claro, la situación que se presenta es esta:
*Al añadir un proyecto recién creado de Laravel, Netbeans lanza el indicador de errores de sintaxis **«Esto obviamente aplica como falsos errores»**.*

El directorio que posee los supuestos errores es el **vendor/** podríamos suponer que para solucionar esto simplemente ignoramos el directorio usando la opción:

```
Properties > Ignored Folders > Add Folder
```

Sin embargo esta solución si bien elimina el indicador rojo para errores de sintaxis, también suprime el completado correspondiente al análisis de código al directorio **vendor/**.

A continuación propondré una solución bastante arcaica, esperando encontrar mejores respuestas.

PD: este error no aplica para casos en los que se puedan desactivar ciertas advertencias usando las opciones del editor `Options > Editor > Hints > PHP`.

Answer (score 0):

La solución general que le he encontrado es un truco que solo funciona para directorios que el usuario pueda excluir del árbol de proyectos de netbeans que sigue el siguiente algoritmo:

1. crear un enlace del directorio que genera el error de sintaxis en un lugar fuera del proyecto.
2. ignorar el directorio que genera el error.
3. agregar el enlace creado a las rutas incluidas de la configuración del proyecto.

---

> **Solución en Linux**

Supongase que nuestro directorio de proyecto es:

```shell
/var/www/html/stackoverflow
```

[image: proyecto con falsos errores de sintaxis]

El primer paso es crear un enlace del directorio fuera del proyecto, para lo que podemos usar algo mas o menos así:

```shell
ln -s /var/www/html/stackoverflow/vendor ~/proyectos/otros/vendor-stackoverflow
```

[image: enlace a vendor del proyecto]

El segundo paso es ignorar el directorio que genera el error de sintaxis, presionando click derecho sobre el proyecto y seleccionando la opcion `Properties`, luego ir a la sección `Ignored Folders` y agregar el fichero mencionado.

[image: Propiedades de netbeans]

[image: Adición del directorio a ignorar]

Esto quitara el directorio del árbol de proyectos de netbeans al igual que  la notificación de error, pero también suprimirá el auto-completado correspondiente al análisis de código a este directorio, así que para solucionar este problema emergente: Finalmente nos dirigimos a la sección `Include Path` de la propiedades del proyecto y agregamos en la pestaña `Private` el enlace simbolico que hemos creado con anterioridad

[image: adicion del fichero ignorado]

El resultado será la ausencia del fastidioso notificador rojo y la permanencia del auto-completado de nuestras librerías, algo así:

[image: proceso exitoso]

> **Solución en Windows** {Versiones superior a Vista}

En windows solo difiere del primer paso puesto la manera de crear enlaces es un tanto diferente, en esta caso el comando será algo mas o menos así:

```
mklink /j c:\xampp\stackoverflow\vendor  c:\users\proyecto\vendor-stackoverflow
```

Suponiendo claro esta que nuestro proyecto esta almacenado en `c:\xampp\stackoverflow`.

De aquí en adelante solo debe seguir los pasos mencionados y todo debería funcionar correctamente.